# Discover the current position of a View after some transformations are aplied

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I  did this to scale a view:

```
            child.setPivotX(200);
            child.setPivotY(150);
            child.setScaleX(2);
            child.setScaleY(2);
```

The View is scaled but I'm trying to get it's new position on screen and it's never change.

I tried with:

```
        int[] location = new int[2];
        child.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Even child.getLeft(), getTop(), getRight() and getBottom() also never changes.

Comment: have you tried calling invalidate() on the child to prompt the values to update?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a combination of `getX`,`getY`, `getWidth` & `getHeight`?

Comment: Those values aren't updated also. If it was, I'm able to use them for what I need